# NodeJS + Express: Server cannot resolve GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE requests (Status 404)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const port = process.env.PORT ||9999
const goals = require('./routes/goalRoutes')
const app = express()

app.use('/api/goals', goals)
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

`goalRoutes.js` defines a route `api/goals`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { createGoal, getGoals, updateGoal, deleteGoal, } = require('../controllers/goalController')

router.route('/').post(createGoal).get(getGoals)
router.route('/:id').put(updateGoal).delete(deleteGoal)

module.exports = router
```

`goalController.js` gives functionality to that route

```
//@desc     Create goal
//@route    POST /api/goals
//@access Private
const createGoal = (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: "Create goal"})
}

//@desc     Get goals
//@route    GET /api/goals
//@access Private
const getGoals = (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: "Read goals"})
}

//@desc     Update goal
//@route    PUT /api/goals:id
//@access Private
const updateGoal = (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: `Update this goal: ${req.params.id}`})
}

//@desc     Get goals
//@route    DELETE /api/goal/:id
//@access Private
const deleteGoal = (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: `Delete this goal: ${req.params.id}`})
}

module.exports = {
    createGoal,
    getGoals,
    updateGoal,
    deleteGoal,
}
```

I have created a route (intended as `/api/goals`) and controllers for that route. I then used the controllers found in `goalController.js` to handle GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE requests and connected that to `goalRoutes.js`.

Using Postman for testing, I can only resolve these requests with a 404 status.

My initial thought process was that I didn't correctly import the controller functions into `goalRoutes.js`, but I seem to have exported them as an object just fine and Node doesn't seem to have an issue with anything at runtime.

I used to have the body of the controllers' functions within the callback functions of `router.get`, `router.post`, `router.put`, and `router.delete` but that was really messy. I would strongly prefer not to go back to that mess.

I am at a loss. *What's stopping the callback functions of `router.route` to use the controller functions? Why does Postman receive 404?*

I apologize if my terminology sucks. I'm a total beginner at Javascript.

Comment: _"I'm a total beginner at Javascript"_... with well structured, well documented code. You're off to a great start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've registered all your controllers as [error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers).

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have **four arguments** instead of three: `(err, req, res, next)`

Remove the first `err` parameters from each of them

```js
const createGoal = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({message: "Create goal"})
}

const getGoals = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({message: "Read goals"})
}

const updateGoal = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({message: `Update this goal: ${req.params.id}`})
}

const deleteGoal = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({message: `Delete this goal: ${req.params.id}`})
}
```

FYI, the default response status when using `res.json()` is 200.

Answer (score -1):

if you use nodejs module import
try implementing this into your code, it works

```
export default ()=> {
    const app = Router()

    RolesRoute(app)
    auth(app)
    FlightRoute(app)
    MaintenanceRoute(app)
    Books(app)

    app.use('/user',UserRoute())

    app.use('/engineer', EngineerRoute())
    app.use('/instructor', InstructorRoute())

    return app
}
```

***Auth Routes***

```
import { Router } from 'express'

import {AuthValidator} from "../../../lib/validator";
import AuthController from "../../../controllers/auth.controller";
import {isAdmin, isAuth} from "../../../lib/middleware/auth";

const route = Router();
export default (app)=> {
    app.use('/auth', route);

    /**
     * Sign in
     */
    route.post("/signIn", AuthValidator.signInValidator, AuthController.signIn)

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look anything like OP's code. They are also clearly not using ES6 modules